# How set dynamic class in pug?

Tags: pug

How do I set a dynamic class in Pug in a loop?
I want to have the same output as below:

```
.main 
  span.player1
  span.player2
  span.player3
  span.player4
```

How can I use this loop to implement the code above?

```
.main 
 each item in [1,2,3,4]
  span.player+item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this with the traditional `class` attribute:

```
.main 
  each item in [1,2,3,4]
    span(class="player"+item)
```

In Pug, doing `p.some-class` is equivalent to `p(class="some-class")`, as that is what it compiles down to anyway, when transformed into HTML.